# Joomla listing all contacts in multiple categories

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.2

Using the default Joomla Contacts Component.
On a single webpage I want to list all contacts in multiple categories. Joomla has the option for listing up several categories and provides a link to each category. But it does not provide the option for listing up the contacts directly on the same page.

I have 1 main empty category with 2 subcategories. I created a menu Item showing this main category with 2 subcategories.
Underneath each subcategroy I would like to list the contacts.

In the default_children.php template in category/ I tried making some (overriding) changes whit no success. I'm not really familiar with php...
I think loading the 'items' template would be the most correct way but how can I achieve this?

```
<?php foreach ($this->children[$this->category->id] as $id => $child) : ?>
    $this->category = $child;
    echo $this->loadTemplate('items');
<?php endforeach;>
```

Tried several thing to make this work but it keeps showing the message that no items are present in the category.

Why does $child->hasChildren() return 0? My categories are not empty...

Comment: I'd use tags instead of categories. Tag all of your contacts with the same tag (you can use bulk processing for this) and then show a tagged items list.

Comment: unfortunately this only displays a link for each contact to a separate page

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing, although I figured out a slightly different way of doing it.

I stepped away from the CMS to generate the display, and added a PHP include to the page based on it's ID.

Then in the include, I just hard-coded all the contact info into the one page.

The include was then added to a single contact (so the contact form was displayed at the bottom, with a grid view of all contacts above it)

This allowed me to style the contacts and their parent categories in whatever way I wanted.